# Event handling in datatables when click on button as no of times that many times image opens

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image, postgresql-9.3

I am developing a program in which I use datatables, which loads dynamically with data using query and adding two buttons. It works very fine.
When I click first button an image is opened in modal. when I click same button, Image opens twice. This procedure continues as no of times I clicked on same button no of times images opens back to back.
My `php` code is like this:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-lg-12" style="margin-top:30px; ">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading clickable">
        <h3 class="panel-title">District Wise Sorting List TP Scheme Details</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body" style="overflow-x:scroll">
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="tps_det">
          <thead>
            <tr class="success">
              <th>Sr ID</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>District</th>
              <th>City</th>
              <th>Button</th>
              <th>Redirect</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <?php do { ?>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <?php echo $row_Recordset1[ 'id']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $row_Recordset1[ 'name']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $row_Recordset1[ 'district']. "</br>" ; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $row_Recordset1[ 'city']. "</br>" ; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php if( $row_Recordset1[ 'buttonoff']=='yes' ) { echo '<button type="button" id="'.$row_Recordset1[ 'name']. '" name="btn_'.$row_Recordset1[ 'name'].
              '" onClick="funct(this);"  ><img src="../data/green_circle.png" style="text-align:center;width:25px;height=25px;" /></button>'; } if( $row_Recordset1[ 'buttonoff']=='no' ) { echo '<button type="button" id="no_off" name="btn_'.$row_Recordset1[ 'name']. '" ><img src="../data/red_circle.png" style="text-align:center;width:25px;height=25px;" /></button>'; } ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" id="sub" name="redirect" onClick="funct(this);">Redirect</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <?php //$i++; } while ($row_Recordset1=p g_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

in javascript procedure, I first check image is present at given source, if it presents then approproate image opens in modal and image is not present then default image is loads in modal.
My problem is that, when I click same button Image should opens only once.

How I do this.

My `javascript` code is like this

```js
theTable = $('#dtble').dataTable({
  "paging": true,
  "lengthChange": true,
  "searching": true,
  "ordering": false,
  "info": true,
  "autoWidth": true
});

function funct(value) {

  var id1 = $(value).attr('id');
  var idname = $(value).attr('name');

  $('#dtble tbody').on('click', 'button', function() {

    var data = theTable.api().row($(this).parents('tr')).data();

    var name = data[1];
    var id = data[0];

    if (id1 == 'sub' && idname == 'redirect') {


      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../select/get_id.php",
        data: 'name=' + name,
        success: function(data1) {
          //alert(data1);
          window.location = '../index_new.php?var=' + data1 + '&name=' + name;
        }
      });
    }

    if (idname == "btn_" + name && id1 == id) {
      var image_url = "../photo/" + name + ".JPG";
      $.get(image_url)
        .done(function() {

          BootstrapDialog.show({

            title: 'Name:- ' + name,
            message: '<img class="image_nm" id="image_nm" src="../photo/' + name + '.JPG" height=800 width=500 style="margin-left:30px;"> '
          });

        }).fail(function() {

          BootstrapDialog.show({

            title: 'Name:- ' + name,
            message: '<img class="image_nm" id="image_nm" src="../photo/default.png" height=800 width=500 style="margin-left:30px;"> '
          });
        });
    }
  });
}
```